# const char pointer assignments

Tags: c, string, constants

Are the following assignments valid? Or will any of these create problems. Please suggest.

```
const char * c1;  
const char * c2; 
const char * c3;
char * c4;

c2 = c1;
c2 = c3;
c2 = c4;
```

What if I do the following, is that ok thing to do?

```
const char * c5 = "xyz";
char * c6 = "abc";

c2 = c5;
c2 = c6;
```

Comment: @ Kshitij Mehta - not a homework, we are facing memory issue with our vast code base. So please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user You've asked the same question a few times now. We've answered them over and over. Your edit to this question adds nothing. It just repeats what you asked above.

Comment: I apologise if I am asking same thing. Maybe my understanding with pointers is not acurate.

Comment: Perhaps you could try and explain what you are struggling to understand. I think you need to try something different because this question is going to get the same answer each time your ask it!  ;-)  Try and express yourself in a different way from how you have done thus far.

Answer (score 41):

In your mind draw a line through the asterik. To the left is what is being pointed to and to the right what type of pointer

For example

1. `const char * const p` - The pointer `p` is constant and so are the characters that `p` points to - i.e. cannot change both the pointer and the contents to what `p` points to
2. `const char * p` - `p` points to constant characters. You can change the value of `p` and get it to point to different constant characters. But whatever `p` points to, you cannot change the contents.
3. `char * const p` - You are unable to change the pointer but can change the contents

and finally

1. `char * p` - Everything is up for grabs

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you mean to have 2 *s in the first example?

Comment: Very clear. Nice post. I was just scouring wondering about why I could change a `const char* ptr` as an input arg, and this clarified perfectly. I'm out of votes for another 40 minutes, so I'll ++ after that.

Comment: without this answer I would never understand the difference between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 9):

All are valid statements as along you don't dereference them because all the pointers are left uninitalized or aren't pointing to any valid memory locations.

And they are valid because pointer is not constant but the value pointed by the pointer is constant. So, pointers here are reassignable to point to a different location.

Answer (score 3):

These assignments are all perfectly valid as I and others have explained in your recent run of near identical questions.

A `const char*` is a pointer to memory that cannot be modified using that pointer. Nothing here can circumvent that. The compiler would object if you assigned `c4 = c1` since then that would circumvent the const.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are valid, the only problematic line is `char * c6 = "abc";`: here "abc" is a const literal so assigning it to a non-const pointer is not safe, and should at least generate a warning if not a compile error (I did not try to compile it).