# warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type

Tags: c, compiler-errors, constants, compiler-warnings

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(int **p)
{
    int j=11;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
int main(void)
{
    int i = 10;
    int *const p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

On compilation:

```
example.c:12:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
  foo(&p);
example.c:2:6: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int * const*’
  void foo(int **p)
```

On run:

```
11 11
```

Here p is a constant pointer so why there is no error for changing its content and only just warning?

My doubt for above program is because of following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int var1 = 0, var2 = 0;
    int *const ptr = &var1;
    ptr = &var2;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

On compilation:

```
error: assignment of read-only variable ‘ptr’
    ptr = &var2;
```

Comment: The [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736049/const-char-pointer-assignments/7738315#7738315) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

`int * const p;` means **Const pointer to an int**, where p cannot point to a different location. So, You got warning.

Answer (score 0):

> Why there is no error here for changing the constant location and only
>   just warning?

**Case1**

In fact in :

```
void foo(int **p) // p is a pointer to pointer to int
 {
    int j=11;
    *p = &j;  //equivalent of p = &i in main()
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

You're not changing the value of `p` in main. Are you?

By

```
*p = &j;
```

You're just changing the value stored in `main()`'s p.

**Case2**

```
ptr = &var2; // You are making ptr point to the memory address of &var2
```

This is illegal as `ptr` is `constant`.

Answer (score 0):

`int * const p` is a const pointer to `int` (location of `p` is for read only)

the prototype of `foo` must be

`void foo(int * const *p)` --> a pointer to const pointer to `int` (location of `*p` is for read only)

```
*p = &j;

error: assignment of read-only location ‘*p’
```

But this is valid:

`**p = j;` --> dereferencing `*p` = accessing `i` in `main`

You are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int * const *p)
{
    int j = 11;

    **p = j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 10;
    int * const p = &i;

    foo(&p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
11 11
```

Same for

```
int var1 = 0, var2 = 0;
int *const ptr = &var1;
ptr = &var2; <-- You can not change the location of ptr
```

Answer (score 0):

> why there is no error for changing its content and only just warning?

In the 1st case you get a warning "only" as you just *prepare* the route into disaster by passing a `const` into a context where it could be misused, that is being assigned something. However its not clear whether is really gets something assigned.

In the 2nd case the code actually *does* what it may not, that is assigning to  a `const`, so the compiler treats it as an error.