# Why this c++ code will not occur an error for the const

Tags: c++, constants

```
char* s1 = new char[30];
char s2[] = "is not";
const char* s3 = "likes";
s3 = "allows";
strcpy( s2, s3 );
sprintf( s1, "%s %s %s using functions.", "C++", s2, "fast code" );
printf( "String was : %s\n", s1 );
delete[] s1;
```

I was confused at the

```
const char* s3 = "likes";
s3 = "allows";
```

Because I think s3 is a const, so it cannot alter. However, when `s3 = "allows"` it works. Why?

Comment: [This answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736049/const-char-pointer-assignments/7738315#7738315)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think s3 is a const

No, `s3` is not const itself, it's pointer to const, so `s3 = "allows";` is fine, and `*s3 = 'n';` will fail instead.

If you meant const pointer, `char* const s3` and `const char* const s3` are both const pointer, and then `s3 = "allows";` will fail.

**Summary** (note the position of `const`)

`char* s3` is non-const pointer to non-const, both `s3 = "allows";` and `*s3 = 'n';` are fine.
`const char* s3` is non-const pointer to const, `s3 = "allows";` is fine and `*s3 = 'n';` fails.
`char* const s3` is const pointer to non-const, `s3 = "allows";` fails and `*s3 = 'n';` is fine.
`const char* const s3` is const pointer to const, both `s3 = "allows";` and `*s3 = 'n';` will fail.

See [Constness of pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Constness).

Comment: Really helps me a lot. Many thanks.