# const char variable why does it work if I modify it?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    const char *usuario= NULL;
    while(*envp)
    {
        char *str = *envp++;
        //if(strcmp(str,"USERNAME")==0)
        if(str[0] == 'U' && str[1] == 'S' && str[2]=='E' && str[3]=='R' && str[4] == 'N')
        {
            usuario = str;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(usuario != NULL)
    {
        printf("Hola, bienvenido al programa %s",usuario);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And my question is, why is it working? That "usuario" variable was defined as NULL is of CONST type. It's assumed that those variables can't be modified throughout the program, but then within the while it was modified by `usuario = str;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736049/const-char-pointer-assignments

Comment: `usuario` is not `const`.  What it points to is `const`.

Comment: thx Micho, a question, How do I put that gray box in the code? I used "`  `" but didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`usuario` is not constant in this case.

**Tip:** Pointer declarations must be read **from right to left**

Try reading

```
const char *usuario= NULL;
```

from right to left, in this case, `usuario is a pointer to constant char`

To declare `usuario` as constant, do

```
const char * const usuario= NULL;
```

Above code snippet will make `usuario` **constant**.

Try reading above code snippet from right to left, in this case, `usuario is a constant pointer to a constant char`

Comment: Thank you friend! a thing, in this case (in my code above) it is necessary use "const" before char * usuarui=NULL?
I don't quite understand what is the purpose of  use "const" in that code...

Comment: @EmiliOrtega no, it's not necessary here.

Comment: thx, and lastly, Could you tell me in which case it is advisable to use it?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega use it when you want your pointer to point at a contant object