# is it ok to change const char* variable?

Tags: c, string

```
const char* ch  = "text";
ch  = "Long text";
```

Is it OK to write code like this? Is it possible to have buffer overflow? or maybe it can write to address which is not allowed?

Comment: All these lines are doing is reassigning a pointer, you aren't writing to any other memory

Comment: @UnholySheep I think we should treat pointers like arrays we can write to address which is not allowed but it can cause a trouble. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, @Kanony, you are wrong.  It is utterly routine to assign new values to variables of pointer type.  It is done all the time, and the fact that you can do it at all is among the key functional differences between pointers and arrays.  Do note that such changes don't move anything around in memory, however.  They just replace a pointer to one address with a pointer to a different address.

Comment: Perhaps this would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/7738315/892256. In this context it applies for both C and C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declaration:

```
const char* ch = "text";
```

Only states that what `ch` *points to* is `const`.  It doesn't say that `ch` *itself* it `const`.

What is `ch` is being initialized with is the address of a string literal, and string literals are read-only.  When you then do this:

```
ch  = "Long text";
```

You're assigning to `ch` the address of a *different* string literal.  So what you're doing is well defined.

Had you attempted to do this:

```
ch[0] = 'X';
```

You would get a compiler error because you're trying to modify something that is `const`.  Had you left off the `const` qualifier and done this, your code would most likely crash because you're attempting to modify a string literal which is read-only.

Comment: I think it would be reasonable to say if ch were passed as (char*) via a cast to a function that attempts to write to it, then the implementation will probably cause a bus error by attempting to write to a read-only data segment. That, instead of a compiler error. That might be where the OP is going.

Comment: can you tell me why compiler gives me same address every time? I defined 20 variables between them but `ch` doesn't want to change address

Comment: @Kanony It's not clear exactly what you mean by that.  Do you mean the address of `ch` itself, i.e. `&ch`?  If so, that never changes for as long as `ch` is in scope.  The address it *points to* can change but not its own address.

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose your code into the following one to better understand what you are doing:

```
const char* ch;
ch = "text";
ch = "Long text";
```

Another thing you need to be aware of is that any hard coded string is stored on memory and when you use it in a C expression, they get the value of the pointer to the first character in the string. And that's why your code would work flawlessly and in this case there are **no overflows** even if the second string were 20 million characters long.

I will make it more clear by using an example. When you execute the program, if the string "text" is loaded in memory at the address 0x0100 and "Long text" is loaded at 0x0105 (they are contiguous), then after executing `ch = "text"`, ch will have the value 0x0100, and after executing `ch = "long text"`, ch will have the value 0x0105. In this case, both strings are allocated in memory, you are not writing inside memory.

I'm going OT for now because I read your comment to your question while writing this answer. Please do **not** treat pointers like arrays. A pointer is a variable that holds a (logical) memory address, whereas an array is something different. I understand the confusion, though, because arrays in C, when used inside expressions, they get the value of the pointer to their first elements.

Let me explain better: you can have a static array in C (let's say, of `int`)by simply writing `int arr[10]` (where in place of 10 you can write any *fixed* number you want). `arr` is an array, but whenever used inside an expression such as `arr[5] = 123` `arr` gets converted to a pointer to the first element of the array `arr` (that is `arr[0]`). Why does that work? Because the `[]` operator simply means the following

```
var[N] <===> *(var+N)
```

Nothing more, nothing less.

Ok, let's get back on track. If you had a dynamic array, which is a logically contiguous space in memory which size is fixed at any given time in your program (I mean that the size can change if you explicitly tell it so) and you had *copied* the strings into that memory space, then, you would be right. If you did the following, then you would be right:

```
char str[5];
char *mystr = "text"
int i;

for (i = 0; mystr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    str[i] = mystr[i]
str[i] = mystr[i]  //str is supposed to be a 0-terminated string

char *mystr2 = "long text"
for (i = 0; mystr2[i] != '\0'; i++){
     str[i] = mystr2[i]
str[i] = mystr2[i]  //str is supposed to be a 0-terminated string
```

Or the following:

```
char *str;
char *mystr = "text"
int i;

str = malloc(5 * sizeof(char))

for (i = 0; mystr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    str[i] = mystr[i]
str[i] = mystr[i]  //str is supposed to be a 0-terminated string

char *mystr2 = "long text"
for (i = 0; mystr2[i] != '\0'; i++){
     str[i] = mystr2[i]
str[i] = mystr2[i]  //str is supposed to be a 0-terminated string
```

But not with the following code:

```
char *str;
char *mystr = "text"
int i;

str = malloc(5 * sizeof(char))

for (i = 0; mystr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    str[i] = mystr[i]
str[i] = mystr[i]  //str is supposed to be a 0-terminated string

char *mystr2 = "long text"

str = realloc((strlen(mystr2)+1) * sizeof(char))

for (i = 0; mystr2[i] != '\0'; i++){
     str[i] = mystr2[i]
str[i] = mystr2[i]  //str is supposed to be a 0-terminated string
```

Please note that in the latter two code pieces, I copy and pasted the original code, where the array was allocated on the stack and not dynamically allocated on the heap, however, in the former piece of code `str` is an array and in the latter two pieces it is a pointer.
Also notice that the value of the pointer has nothing to do with the content of the memory at that address. So if you did:

```
char *str;
char *mystr = "text"
int i;

str = malloc(5 * sizeof(char))

for (i = 0; mystr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    str[i] = mystr[i]
str[i] = mystr[i]  //str is supposed to be a 0-terminated string

char *mystr2 = "long text"
str = mystr2
```

it would work without any overflow. That's because the only thing you did was to replace the value of the pointer stored in the `str` variable to the value of the pointer stored in `mystr2`: they are different parts of the memory!

I hope that this answers clarifies some obscure points.